# Crystal report for the project

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am doing a project using vb.net and sql server. I want to know how to create crystal report dynamically,i.e, when the user press the "Create report" button a form has to display where he can drag and drop the fields whichever he wants to display and save the report for future use

Answer (score 0):

is not clear, you want a crystal report designer like the one in visual studio?
if so, you can check http://www.brothersoft.com/crystal-reports-download-79905.html

if not explain better.

Comment: I have been trying to create crystal reports at run time through VB.NET. What I mean by this is writing the all the code to build a report in VB.NET then passing it to CR Viewer. I am trying to create a report generator where a user would choose columns, filters and group-by's from a VB.NET GUI

Comment: so i think the tool above may be usefull for you